# Laravel 5.7 on apache error Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, laravel, openssl

I'm setting Laravel 5.7 on Apache 2.4 using PHP 7.1.26.
I configured everything like documentations.
But I'm getting the error below:

> Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

I've already change PHP version to 7.2 and nothing.
I've already copied the file libeay32.dll to Apache and nothing

These are my modules in PHP

> [PHP Modules]
>   bcmath
>   calendar
>   Core
>   ctype
>   curl
>   date
>   dom
>   exif
>   fileinfo
>   filter
>   gd
>   gettext
>   gmp
>   hash
>   iconv
>   imap
>   intl
>   json
>   ldap
>   libxml
>   mbstring
>   mcrypt
>   mysqli
>   mysqlnd
>   odbc
>   openssl
>   pcre
>   PDO
>   PDO_ODBC
>   pdo_pgsql
>   pdo_sqlite
>   pgsql
>   Phar
>   readline
>   Reflection
>   session
>   SimpleXML
>   soap
>   sockets
>   SPL
>   standard
>   tidy
>   tokenizer
>   wddx
>   xml
>   xmlreader
>   xmlrpc
>   xmlwriter
>   xsl
>   zip
>   zlib

Answer (score 4):

I've just found there is a case I have to set a full path for PHP extension in `php.ini`.

When I executed PHP manually, it loaded extensions properly, but when it's via apache, it tried to load from the wrong path.

```
extension_dir = "C:\full path for PHP ext\ext"
```

Comment: After 2 hours of searching, I found this helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`openssl_cipher_iv_length()` is a [standard PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php) from the OpenSSL module. Your error message says:

```
undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()
```

Note how the function name is preceded by `Illuminate\Encryption` -- this indicates that PHP thinks the function is located in the `Illuminate\Encryption` namespace, but it's not. To fix this, you can explicitly associate the function call to the root namespace by prefixing it with a backslash:

```
\openssl_cipher_iv_length()
```

This error could also mean that `openssl_cipher_iv_length()` is simply not available anywhere, and the `Illuminate\Encryption` namespace is just the last place that it looked. In this case, you'll need to ensure you have the OpenSSL module installed -- but note that the command line config is different than the embedded web server config. I.e., running `php -m` from the command line might report that OpenSSL is available, but it might not be loaded for the web server version. So run `phpinfo()` inside a page served by your web server to verify that OpenSSL is indeed loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just Run `composer update` command from laravel installation directory
And make sure **extension=php_openssl.dll** is enabled in php.ini

Restart Apache Server...

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

try Restart Apache Server. My problem fixed.